# what is flutter Hive equivalent of removeWhere?

Tags: list, flutter, dart

How I can delete value of List in flutter Hive ??

```
example list = [
record(
    name: 'john',
    class: 'Coffee',
  ),
record(
    name: 'sarah',
    class: 'Coffee',
  ),
record(
    name: 'rala',
    class: 'Water',
  ),
];
```

as you can see I have multiple value and want to delete all record that contains value of coffee
but Hive dnt have such as function that can do that

edit: Iam using Box.add function to add value using auto increment key
Iam thingking about delete all the box in hivedb and putAll updated list in var to Hive but iam open to other more effective way or advice

thanks for those who read this

Comment: Add your hive box definition and the way your **put()** entries inside of it.

Comment: iam use box.add method and auto use increment key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hive` doesn't have `removeWhere` and you should use `Dart` methods to do something

Comment: I literally clear the Box so the value is clear 
but when I assign new value with new key it dsnt accept that because duplicate object

Comment: @TonyHart you should delete by key or id such as using `get` method

Answer (score 0):

so I reached Hive repo according to this https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/738
and I also want to share my code if there are someone need if ur need is like me

```
List<BudgetCard> listDelete = localBudget.values.toList();
    for (int i = 0; i < listDelete.length; i++) {
      if (listDelete[i].budgetWallet == walletID) {
        localBudget.deleteAt(i);
      }
    }
```

Thank you for all who respond to my Question!!